# Would it be performant for this query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (b:Brand {brandname:'Apple'})<-[r1]-(s:Product {type:'Phone'})-[r2]-> (o:Attributes)
WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE key CONTAINS 'ROM')
RETURN s, b, o
```

I have both 'brandname' and 'type' indexes on Brand and Product. If in the graph there are many less brands than products, would it be faster for this query if I have also a relationship from Brand to Product, so that I can switch the direction of the query:

```
MATCH (b:Brand {brandname:'Apple'})-[r1]->(s:Product {type:'Phone'})-[r2]-> (o:Attributes)
WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE key CONTAINS 'ROM')
RETURN s, b, o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traversing a relationship in either direction is equally efficient.

So, switching the direction of the relationship will not make a difference.

Comment: If I use "index hint" for nodes of less instances, i.e. Brand, would that make a difference?

Comment: Since locating an item in an index has `O(log N)` complexity, that might make a noticeable difference if the number of instances differ by orders of magnitude. But the planner may already be deciding to using that index. Nevertheless, it wouldn't hurt to add such a hint if you are sure the relative numbers will always significantly differ in the same way.